# how to use ejs / angular array filtering on bulk elements

Tags: angularjs, filter, ejs, prerender

I'm having trouble using dynamic filters using ejs templating engine. I actually don't know if that's possible. I'm using angular on the front end and am trying to have a search box that sorts out html blocks containing the string typed in the input. That's my question: What is the best way to go about making an input box and sorting out the elements that contains the string?

So far I had to use ejs templating to prerender my html for SEO purposes and was successful. I migrated from using ng repeat on my element to use ejs:

```
<%= for loop %>
```

it works but now I can't sort out the group of elements using ng-model and angular filters

Thanks in advance for the help

This is the website http://unimag.herokuapp.com/revista

revista.ejs

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <input class="revista-form-control col-xs-6 col-md-9" ng-model="viewEdition" type="text" placeholder="Buscar Edicion" >   
                <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-6 col-md-3">Buscar</button><br>
            </div><br>
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="votes" value="-upvotes"> Ordenar Por Likes</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" ng-model="votes" value=""> Off</label><br>
        </div>
<% for(var i=0; i < revistas.length; i++) {%>               
            <div ng-init="getLiked('<%= revistaString %>', <%= i %>)" class="revista-box col-md-4">
                <img ng-mouseover="hoverAudio()" width="100%" ng-src="<%= revistas[i].img0 %>">
                <div class="after">
                    <h2><%= revistas[i].edition %></h2>
                    <a href="/revista/<%= revistas[i]._id %>"><button class="btn btn-primary">Explorar Edicion</button></a>
                    <div style="font-family: Arial;">
                        <span ng-show="!check(<%= i %>)" style="cursor: pointer; color: white; text-align: right;" 
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes('<%= revistaString %>', <%= i %>)"></span>
                        <span ng-show="check(<%= i %>)" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue; text-align: right;" 
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="decrementUpvotes('<%= revistaString %>', <%= i %>)"></span>
                        Likes {{ revistaObject[<%= i %>].upvotes }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
```